# geth reports nothing after allocating cache and handles

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

> INFO [05-16|10:32:21] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/windows-amd64/go1.8.
>   1
>   INFO [05-16|10:32:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\Users\Tariq\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\ge
>   th\chaindata cache=128 handles=1024

the disk is being used by geth while this is happening, and then after say 20 minutes? geth closes it self,
do i have to redownload the blockchain? is there another solution since it takes quite some time for me to sync.

Comment: You could use geth's light mode, when geth stops what message it gives you?

Answer (score 2):

Is the geth data directory on a network share, USB key or other slowish storage medium? I saw the same issue when I moved the geth data directory from an SSD to a network share. It moved past this stage after about 5 minutes (instead of a few seconds) and eventually started syncing.

I did not see geth exit on its own as you did. To troubleshoot that you could try increasing the verbosity level:

```
$ geth --verbosity 6 console
```

Comment: I changed my drive and it sat there for a few minutes too, adding the verbosity flag showed me it was working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Delete the `LOCK` file in `geth`**

It is possible that this file was left after a forced shut down and it's preventing further synchronization.

**How do I find it?**

The Ethereum Wallet is installed in different locations depending on your operating system:

- `~/.ethereum` on Linux
- `~/Library/Ethereum` on OS X
- `~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum` on Windows

You may need to show hidden files to see these directories on your system.

Locate the `geth` sub-directory and delete the file named `LOCK`. This should enable `geth` to proceed with synchronization.

**How do I sync from scratch now the lock is gone?**

If you want to restart synchronization from scratch, as fast as possible, then you need to delete the contents of the `chaindata` sub-directory (same level as the `geth` directory earlier). You can do this through `geth` by issuing the command

`geth removedb`

If that command hangs, then you've still got the `LOCK` issue so delete it again.

To start synchronization issue the command

`geth --syncmode=fast --cache 1024`

In a few seconds your screen should be filled with block downloads. If you have a lot of memory consider `--cache 2048`.